# Set caret to start of line in WPF RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a RichTextBox containing lines of text (each line a paragraph), and I have a line number that represents an error. I want to set the caret to be at the start of that line. How?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't got a working installation of C# on my machine at the moment, but from looking at the docs it seems you should be able to first locate the paragraph you want (probably by enumerating through them, there does not seem to be an index function) in `yourFlowDocument.Blocks` and then:

```
TextPointer paragraphStart = paragraph.ElementStart;
richTextBox.CaretPosition = paragraphStart;
```

Comment: Thanks Mia! I had concluded that this was one way to go about it, but the fact that they hide the indexer makes me suspect that they really don't want you doing this sort of thing. The biggest problem I see is that when someone starts to edit the text I cannot control the structure (1 line per paragraph or run) - it's all done for me. So either I have to waste time restructuring after every change... or something else.

Comment: Agh. Sounds like a pickly pickle indeed. Maybe you could keep the structure in some other collection as well, like a map or something, and manage changes as they happen on input? I wish I could do more to help. Good luck to you!